Prisma, search for two userId in a list
i am making a web app using NextJs, in which i'm currently making the chat rooms.
When a user want to start a conversation the website will check in the db is there is an existing room for these two users. If yes redirect, if no create it then redirect.
My issue here is with the prisma query, i want to select row of rooms where participants are for exemple: [user1 && user2].
Here my schema:
model User {
  userId    Int       @id @default(autoincrement())
  email     String
  username  String
  password  String
  regdate   DateTime  @default(now())
  messages  Message[]
  token     String
  rooms     Room[]

  friends   User[] @relation("friends")
  friendsRelation User[] @relation("friends")

  friendsPending   User[] @relation("friendStatus")
  friendRequests User[] @relation("friendStatus")
}

model Message {
  messageId Int       @id @default(autoincrement())
  content   String
  senddate  DateTime  @default(now())
  author    User?     @relation(fields: [authorId], references: [userId])
  authorId  Int?
  room     Room[]
}

model Room {
  roomId          Int       @id @default(autoincrement())
  isGroup         Boolean   @default(false)
  roomName        String    @default("")
  nameAuto        Boolean   @default(true)
  roomMessages    Message[]
  roomUsers       User[] **WANT TO GET USERS FROM HERE**
}

I tried this query but have issues:
        const room = await prisma.room.findMany({
            where: {
                isGroup: false, // ignore, it's just for excluding groupes
                roomUsers: {
                    userId: [userId, targetUser]
                }
            }
        });  

Hope that someone can help me, thanks in advance.

What does "have issues" mean; what is the error message? Or do you not just get the results you expect?
